# Rails Validation for Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I'm trying to create a custom validation for one of my models on create, my validation limits a user to create one record per day. But I need to add a condition lets the user create multiples records a day if one of the records attributes are unique "job_id".

**my user class**

```
class CareGiver < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
 :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable 
 validates_presence_of :phone, :city, :state, :street, :zip, presence: true, on: :create

  has_many :hours do
    def today
      where(:created_at =>(Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now))
    end
  end

end
```

each hour record has a "job_id". I want users to be able to create one record a day which is working. but if the "job_id" is unique and has no hours logged for it. i want them to be able to create the record.

**record im creating(hours)**

```
class Hour < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :care_giver
  validate :hours_for_the_day, :on => :create

  private 
    def hours_for_the_day
      if care_giver.hours.today.count >= 1 
        errors.add(:base, "Exceeds daily limit")
      end
   end
end
```

Should i maybe add a parameter to this method? Im having trouble understanding how i can achieve this. any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Is the job_id used for a relation to another active record model? Or is it just something arbitrarily generated?

Comment: @Rob Nice thanks for the reply.. its used for a relation. Every time an hour record is created im adding the id for the job it belongs to.

Comment: Thinking about it, why not delegate this behavior to the CareGiver model with a method like log_hour_for_job, then you can do your validations there on both the job and the hour.

Comment: @RobNice can you show me an example of how i would do this?

Comment: Sure, can you add your Job model so I can see the relation it has to the CareGiver and Hour?

Comment: the job model currently has no relation to the hours or caregiver.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to instead have a worked_on date field on Hour and give that a unique validation?

Do you actually want to limit someone to entering one Hour record per day or limit them to having one Hour record of a unique date?

```
class CareGiver < ApplicationRecord
  devise ...

  has_many :hours

  validates_presence_of :phone, ..., presence: true, on: :create
end

class Hour
  validates_uniqueness_of :worked_on
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I (wrongfully) assumed job_id was currently being used to reference the Job model. But since, it's not, it should't be too difficult to add another validation to check for job_id uniqueness on the Hour model. I have not tested this, but I *think* this should work.

```
#other code
validate :unique_job_id, :on => :create

private

def unique_job_id
  if Hour.where(job_id: job_id).any?
    #errors
  end
end
#other stuff
```

Comment: I am still able to create multiple records for jobs is there any way that i can limit this one per day?

Comment: Multiple records for jobs or hours? I thought you wanted to add another validation for the hour to check the uniqueness of the job_id.

Comment: im sorry.. Yes i want to check the uniqueness of the job_id, but i want users to only post 1 hour record for day as well. I pretty much want users that have that jobs to only post 1 hour record for that job. so is there any way i can check the Id in the current hours_for_day method i have?

Comment: Sure, just do the Hours.where(job_id: job_id).any?, if there are any Hours with that job_id, it will return true.

Comment: hmm @Rob Nice for some reason its returning false even when there are records with the same id

Comment: i think there is no value being inserted to job_id so it returns false everytime